# How to deploy a contract when a private chain start?

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

> ethernet vererion: 1.8.x, language: golang 1.11.x

I wrote a smart contract in solidity. The contract's contructor has two parameters like this:

> uint256 _initialAmount, string _tokenName

I compiled this file and got the ABI and bytecode. Now, I want to deploy it to my private chain when the chain node start ( but not by JSON RPC request). I noticed there's a API in types.transaction.go like this:

> func NewContractCreation(nonce uint64, amount *big.Int, gasLimit, uint64, gasPrice *big.Int, data []byte) *Transaction

So, how can I get the 'data' value? is it from ABI or bytecode?

Thanks.

Comment: Missing a language tag.

Comment: The answer depends on what framework and programming language you are using to work with your private chain.